# HSQLDB optimize 1.000.000 bulk insert

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, hsqldb

I need to insert 1.000.000 entries in HSQLDB on Tomcat as fast as possible, but 64m (default MaxPermSize on Tomcat) not enough for this code, and I get "OutOfMemoryError" (I want to insert on default settings).

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO USER (firstName, secondName) VALUES(?,?)");
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "firstName");
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "secondName");
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
connection.commit();
```

I reed this: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_bulk_operations. I set "SET FILES LOG FALSE" but it doesn't help.

1. Is there way to insert 1.000.000 entries with MaxPermSize=64m ?
2. Why on this code tomcat eat so much memory ? There 1.000.000 * 19 (length of "firstName" + "secondName") * 2 (bytes on 1 symbol) = ~40Mb.
3. Why in memory tables inserts go faster then in cached tables ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Can you insert at the batch size of 10000? Is there a need to insert all 1M items in 1 batch?

Comment: Yes I tried, but still did not work. No matter how many batches will be.

Comment: The memory occupation of a `String` object is about 40 bytes plus the legnth of the string multiplied by 2. In your case this gives about 19 (length of strings) + 40=59 bytes for each string, that gives 118 bytes * 1000000 = ~118Mb. So the best solution is to use smaller batches, as pointed out by @nhahtdh.

Comment: If it doesn't work, try closing and reopening the statement at each batch execution, forcing it to release heap allocated memory.

Answer (score 5):

1. Maybe try to do it by smaller sets. It will consume less memory and would probably be more efficient.
2. Calculating the size of the memory is much much more harder. For example, you won't have firstName stored 1 million time, the value will be internalized, but you will have to store the reference 1 million times. Then, all your libraries consume memories, etc...
3. What do you call "cached tables"?

Try that, you will consume less memory at least :

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO USER (firstName, secondName) VALUES(?,?)");
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "firstName");
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "secondName");
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
    if(i % 1000 == 0)
         preparedStatement.executeBatch();
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
connection.commit();
```

EDIT : Are you sure it is because of the perm size? Can you put the stack trace?

Comment: I think, in if statement, after executeBatch() commit will be better.

Comment: If you commit, you commit... That's maybe not what you want to do. Commit is a functionality of the DB and so should only affect the memory of the DB. However since it is en embedded DB, you are probably right, it will save memory. But I repeat, when you commit, you commit....

Comment: Periodic commit is necessary to reduce memory use. Otherwise all 1000000 rows are kept in memory until commit.